# QMqttMessage identify client

Tags: qt, mqtt, mosquitto

In Qt, I have a connection with `QMqttSubscription::messageReceived` signal.

```cpp
MqttSubscriptionManager::MqttSubscriptionManager(QMqttSubscription *sub, QString topic, quint8 qos, QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent),
    topicName(topic),
    qos(qos),
    sub(sub)
{
    connect(sub, &QMqttSubscription::stateChanged, this, &MqttSubscriptionManager::handleStateChanged);
    connect(sub, &QMqttSubscription::messageReceived, this, [this](QMqttMessage msg) {
        handleReceivedMessage(msg.payload());
    });
}

void MqttSubscriptionManager::handleReceivedMessage(QByteArray payload)
{
    qDebug() << QDateTime::currentMSecsSinceEpoch() << " data: " << payload;
    ...
}
```

I receive my message split in three parts, here's an example:

```
1673636330689  data:  "{\"Device ID\":2,\"State\":\"OK\",\"Battery\":15,\"Charging\":false,\"Data\":[{\"code\":1,\"name\":\"par1\",\"value\":29.02,\"udm\":\"%\"},{\"cod"

1673636330708  data:  "e\":2,\"name\":\"par2\",\"value\":40.21,\"udm\":\"%\"},{\"code\":3,\"name\":\"par3\",\"value\":99.90,\"udm\":\"%\"},{\"code\":4,\""

1673636330708  data:  "name\":\"par5\",\"value\":26.32,\"udm\":\"%\"}],\"Technical_Error\":[]}\x03"
```

So, my method `MqttSubscriptionManager::handleReceivedMessage` using a buffer, will wait for the end of the message (x03), and then parse the JSON.

The problem is that, if I have two or more devices connected at the same time (that publish in the same topic), the messages overlap and I have no way of understanding who is sending me what.

Here's an example:

```
1673633766990  data:  "{\"Device ID\":1,\"State\":\"OK\",\"Battery\":69,\"Charging\":false,\"Data\":[{\"code\":1,\"name\":\"par1\",\"value\":0.00,\"udm\":\"%\"},{\"code"
1673633766995  data:  "{\"Device ID\":2,\"State\":\"OK\",\"Battery\":22,\"Charging\":false,\"Data\":[{\"code\":1,\"name\":\"par1\",\"value\":27.60,\"udm\":\"%\"},{\"cod"
1673633767046  data:  "e\":2,\"name\":\"par2\",\"value\":40.53,\"udm\":\"%\"},{\"code\":3,\"name\":\"par3\",\"value\":99.90,\"udm\":\"%\"},{\"code\":4,\""
1673633767046  data:  "name\":\"par4\",\"value\":26.34,\"udm\":\"%\"}],\"Technical_Error\":[]}\x03"
1673633767046  data:  ""


1673633767056  data:  "\":2,\"name\":\"par2\",\"value\":44.79,\"udm\":\"%\"},{\"code\":3,\"name\":\"par3\",\"value\":99.90,\"udm\":\"%\"},{\"code\":4,\"n"
1673633767056  data:  "ame\":\"par4\",\"value\":24.57,\"udm\":\"%\"}],\"Technical_Error\":[]}\x03"
1673633767056  data:  ""
```

So I tried to bypass Qt, then I just used `mosquitto_sub` in CLI.

```
mosquitto_sub -t "Device/Data"
```

But I had the same problem.

I'm using Mosquitto 1.5.8 and Qt 5.12.3

Comment: If you are seeing the same issue with `mosquitto_sub` then it looks like whatever is producing the messages is splitting the data, and sending multiple messages (so you would need to look there). If the sender cannot be fixed then using a device specific topic (e.g. `Device/Data/Dev23`) may help. Note that Mosquitto 1.5.8 is  pretty old...

Comment: As @Brits said this looks like a broken/badly designed publisher breaking a single JSON string into multiple messages